# Issue with TFS build definition and WCF service in a Web Site "Project"

Tags: wcf, tfs, build, publish

I'm trying to create a TFS build definition for a WCF service I'm working on. When I go to set the "Items to Build\Projects to Build," I can't choose any .*proj or .sln file. The source for the service is under the "Visual Studio\WebSites\SERVICE_NAME" directory which does not have a .proj or .sln file.
I've been looking around for any material on the matter and nothing seems to be relevant to my situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have chosen to use a Web Site "project". That was a mistake.

Web sites are not projects. They therefore do not have project files and do not build.

I strongly recommend never using web sites for any serious work. Use a Web Application Project instead (File->New Project and choose "WCF Service Application").

Don't use them for web applications, either.

Comment: Ahhhh.That makes sense...Thanks for the quick answer. (Are there any drawbacks to using this method instead of "Web Site"? I am fairly well along in the dev process.) Therefore, you would suggest simply re-creating the service with "new project\wcf service application"?

Comment: Web Site "Projects" are not suited for professional application development. They are for people familiar with a style of development that considers whatever files may be on disk to be part of the site, and for applications with little code. Anything more interesting than that will cause problems when using a web site. Web services, by definition, are more interesting. Yes, just create a WCF Service Application and copy the code from the original service.