# TFS 2010 not building website (into _PublishedWebsites)

Tags: tfs, web

My .sln file has a website (and a few other web applications). The web applications get published to the _PublishedWebsites directory, but not the website. I am not using a custom build configuration. This happens in both Release and Debug mode.

Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Issue with TFS build definition and WCF service in a Web Site "Project"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7653412/issue-with-tfs-build-definition-and-wcf-service-in-a-web-site-project)

Comment: This is yet another reason to not use Web Site "projects"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During the TFS build it checks the project file for *Imports* which it uses to define the build requirements. The Visual Studio 2010 import for web projects (`$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets`) does not contain a definition for the outputting to *_PublishWebsites* as the Visual Studio 2009 one (`$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v9.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets`)  had.

To solve this you need to edit the web application target file on the build server to enable this functionality.

Additional information and assistance can be found at

- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/zh/tfsbuild/thread/0bd3b8de-0397-41f1-b43a-5ccdd04f9436
- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsbuild/thread/559a53e1-2eeb-48e9-a95f-400154b3333f